# Bootstrap footer

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to add a footer to my webapp with bootstrap.

I use the following html:

```
<footer class="container-fluid footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs text-center">Voltooid:</br>40/80 taken</div>
    <div class="col-xs text-center">Ongepland:</br>5 taken</div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: green;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

**The problem I have is that the width of the columns is not half of the screen. I want 2 columns of 50%.**

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You want to have 2 columns of 50%?

Comment: @ArneBanck correct!

Comment: Then you should just give each column a col-xs-6.

Comment: @ArneBanck tried that already, gives me the same result sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it bootstrap 4?

If it is, col-xs-6 doens't exist anymore. They removed the xs property and now is col-6 for the smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boostrap 4, I recomend this changes:

```
<footer class="container-fluid footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 text-center">Voltooid:<br>40/80 taken</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 text-center">Ongepland:<br>5 taken</div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

If you in mobile version you want two columns, change the col-12 for col-6

If you are using boostrap 3, the code will be:

```
<footer class="container-fluid footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-center">Voltooid:<br>40/80 taken</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-center">Ongepland:<br>5 taken</div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Similarly, if you want two columns in mobile version, change col-xs-12 for col-xs-6 in both blocks.